# Android - file not found while building NDK library

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk

I'm trying to build the SoundTouch library for Android, by following the guide provided within the source code:

> Compiling
>
> To compile the SoundTouch library source codes into an Android native
>   library, open Cygwin/bash shell, go to directory
>   "soundtouch/source/Android-lib/jni" and invoke the NDK compiler with
>   following command:
>
> ```
> $NDK/ndk-build
> ```
>
> This will build binaries for all the supported Android platforms
>   (arm-v5, arm-v7, X86, MIPS etc) of SoundTouch library, plus the JNI
>   wrapper interface as discussed below. The target binaries will be
>   built into the "libs" subdirectory. As long as all these .so binary
>   library versions are included in the APK Application delivery package,
>   the targer Android device can choose the correct library version to
>   use.
>
> Notice that to allow Cygwin/bash to locate the NDK compile scripts,
>   you need to define the location of the NDK installation defined in
>   environment variable "NDK". That's easiest done by adding the NDK path
>   definition at end of your ~/.bash_profile file, for instance as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> NDK=/cygdrive/d/Android/android-ndk-r6
> ```

to do this I go into Terminal in the `SoundTouch/source/android-lib/jni` directory and type the following commands:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
export NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_NDK
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK}
ndk-build
```

Then I get the following error:

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : soundtouch <= soundtouch-jni.cpp
jni/soundtouch-jni.cpp:23:10: fatal error: '../source/SoundStretch/WavFile.h'
      file not found
#include "../source/SoundStretch/WavFile.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
/home/daniele/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk:499: recipe for target 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/soundtouch/soundtouch-jni.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/soundtouch/soundtouch-jni.o] Error 1
```

If I go to that directory the file is there though. Here is a screenshot of the file with it's direcotry:

[image: file dir]

Comment: `../` would take you back to `SoundTouch/source/android-lib`.

Comment: @123 ok,  it should take me to source instead right? How do I do it? what should I edit?

Comment: You can simply include `#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif ` in all of your header files in which you're facing this issue.  `__cplusplus` will be defined for any compilation unit that is being run through the C++ compiler. It works really well. :)